# ioredis prints unnecessary error log messages

Tags: bash, logging, awk

Ioredis NPM package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) prints these error messages unnecessarily in my K8s containers:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: All sentinels are unreachable. Retrying from scratch after 10ms.
    at connectToNext (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/connectors/SentinelConnector/index.js:64:31)
    at SentinelConnector.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/connectors/SentinelConnector/index.js:120:16)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:121:64
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at EventEmitter.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/Redis.js:103:25)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:171:18)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Apparently there is no solution for this bug yet after years of threads (https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/635)

I am wanting to take a different approach and suppress these error messages in my containers before they're printed. Is there a way I can do that using `awk` or something like that? (Sorry not great with Bash commands)